# Ошибка Toast NullPointException

Tags: java, android

Возникает ошибка NullPointException в таком виде кода:

```
Toast toast;
toast.makeText(getContext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```

---

Вот так работает нормально:

```
Toast toast;
toast.makeText(getContext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Не могу понять, почему так происходит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому, что `makeText()` - это статический метод класса Toast, возвращающий экземпляр этого класса. В вашем первом варианте возвращённый объект не присваевается переменной `toast`, на момент вызова `show()` в ней содержится `null` и поэтому возникает ошибка. Правильно сделать так:

```
Toast toast;
toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```

Во втором варианте и переменная-то не нужна:

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение